# Cakephp - URL with uppercase generating duplicate content, redirect to lowercase

Tags: php, regex, redirect, cakephp

I'm using Cakephp 2.x and I am trying to redirect URL's which contain uppercase to lowercase.
For providing more info about the technical part , it is a dictionary which takes a parameter (letter or a word) and then makes a search on the database and in relation of the user's search, it displays a certain result.

What have I done so far is this piece of code in order to be able to redirect those URL's which the user, let's say, by his/her own judgement or mistake inputs letters in uppercase.
In this case, directly when there is an uppercase letter inserted, the result or word must be redirected automatically to lowercase.

´´´

```
 public function comprobar_param($param, $letter = NULL) {
    $param_is_letter = false;
    $param_is_capital_letter = false;
    $categorias_diccionario = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    if(strlen($param) > 0) {
        // If it is a lowercase letter
        $pos_lowercase = strpos($categorias_diccionario, $param);
        $pos_lowercase !== false ? true : false;
        $param_is_letter = $pos_lowercase;
        $pos_uppercase = preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $param);

        //if the letter is a capital letter
        $param_is_capital_letter = !$param_is_letter && $pos_uppercase;
    }

    if(empty($this->request->query)){
        $params_url_str = '';
    } else {
        $params_url_str = '?' . http_build_query($this->request->query);
    }


    if($param_is_capital_letter === true) {
       $this->redirect('/' . DICCIONARIO_MEDICO_URL . '/' . strtolower($param). $params_url_str, 301);
    } elseif($param_is_letter === false) {

        if($letter != NULL) {
            $this->redirect('/' . DICCIONARIO_MEDICO_URL . '/' . $param . $params_url_str, 301);
        } else {
            $this->cacheAction = array(
                'comprobar_param' => '1 year'
            );

          $this->view(null, $param);
          $this->render('view');
        }
    // if we are on the list with lowercase
    } else {
        // if the url doesn't end in slash, we redirect the URL with slash at the end
        if(substr($this->params->url, -1) != '/') {
            $this->redirect('/' . DICCIONARIO_MEDICO_URL . '/' . strtolower($param) . '/' . $params_url_str, 301);
            return;
        }
}
```

´´´

Therefore, the route I have been using inside my routes.php file would be the next:

```
Router::connect('/'.DICCIONARIO_MEDICO_URL . '/:param', array('controller' => 'treatments', 'action' => 'comprobar_param'), array('pass' => array('param' => '')));
```

At this point, I had the possibility to do the redirect on my local server, but when I am trying to test it on my development server, the redirect function is failing.
I am going to point out an example so you can have a glimpse of what I want to achieve: 
http://topdoctors.local/diccionario-medico/Aborto => http://topdoctors.local/diccionario-medico/Aborto

Any suggestion would be welcoming.
Thanks you.

Comment: I feel like you ought to be doing this at the Apache level instead. Here's a resource that may help: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase

Comment: Well,  from my core.php file, I see that in order to configure CakePhp it says : *not* to use mod_rewrite and to use CakePHP pretty URLs, remove these .htaccess files: /.htacces , /app/.htaccess , /app/webroot/.htaccess . With that being said, redirecting URL's generally it has to be done or through the Controller  or through the routes.php

Comment: That's not what that comment intends to say, the non-`mod_rewrite` pretty URLs are for people that can't use `mod_rewrite` (or other URL rewriting measures depending on the server software) for whatever reason, it doesn't mean to say that you can't use pretty URLs with `mod_rewrite`, it's quite the opposite, the URLs are much prettier with `mod_rewrite` than with the `App.baseUrl` functionality, as with the latter you'll always have `/index.php` in your URLs. I'd suggest to give `mod_rewrite` redirects a try and see how it performs.

Comment: Regarding your code problem, you'll have to be a little more specific, "_is failing_" could mean anything, please try to explain what _exactly_ happens. In any case, if you do redirect handling on PHP level I'd strongly suggest to move it into `index.php` and use vanilla PHP, doing it in the controller is way too late, there's no reason to do all the framework processing when you just want to redirect based on the URL.

Comment: The place in which I am working for, redirect handling of URL's with a status 301, .htaccess is not used at all for handling this type of requests. Therefore, we have always to do it on a PHP level scale.  One way maybe would be  through the `routes.php` file which is located inside the `app/Config` folder. I reckon that from there would be also plausible to do it if I am not mistaken. There is got to be a `regex` possible that can be used in order to redirect any parameter given with uppercase letters. Thanks by all means for your suggestions.